# how to make cookie in asp.net that takes url query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, sitecore

intern in company working with asp.net and sitecore here

My very first assignment has to do with adding support for a query parameter that can will enable the editor to see some key names of some buttons for a page.

Now i was thinking that i would make a cookie with httpcookie in the correct controller and somehow get the query parameter into the cookie, could that be done in a way?

many thanks?

Comment: Cookies are key-value pairs, not things that execute code. If you want to store something from the query string into a cookie, you'll have to write serverside or clientside code that does so.

Comment: yes, i was thinking i would call the relevant cookie method in the relevant asp.net controller. And then I was hoping there was someway to "capture" the query string

Comment: am I being foolish in my approach?

Answer (score -2):

You can use a URL querystring parameter to get the value you need on Page Load and then set controls accordingly. As for storing Values you can store whatever you need in ViewState or SessionState and look them up when you need to.

Example below:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
   if(Request.QueryString["switch"] !== null)
   {
        if(Request.QueryString["switch"].ToString()) == "on")
        {
            button.Visible = true;
             ViewState["someval"] = hiddenVal.Text;

        }
        else
        {
            button.Visible = false;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: The question asked about cookies, not ViewState.